# How to get rid of BrowserSync usage for Excel add-in

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, ms-office

I wrote a small Excel add-in using node.js with jQuery. The source code was generated by "yo office". Below is the content of package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "my-office-add-in",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "browser-sync start --config bsconfig.json",
    "validate": "./node_modules/.bin/validate-office-addin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "office-addin-validator": "^1.0.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-js": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.5",
    "@types/office-js": "^0.0.37"
  }
}
```

I need to get rid of BrowserSync usage and use another command to start my application. The reason I need to do that is my Excel add-in is being placed onto a shared folder and used by multiple users. BrowserSync synchronizes views in browsers of different users who work simultaneously.

Can someone show me the alternative solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any package that spins up an https web server.

`http-server` is an alternative you can get using npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

To install: 
`npm install http-server --save-dev`

From there change your `start` script to `"start": "http-server --ssl"`

That will start a server at your root directory and you can navigate to your index file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.